# Как правильно читать json python

Tags: python, json

изучая Python, а именно библиотеку json, столкнулся с непониманием как правильно мне извлечь только те данные, которые нужны?

Пример кусочка json файла ниже. как мне извлечь только id и name?

```json
{
    "state": 0,
    "version": 2,
    "data": {
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 30030535,
                "root": 22125105,
                "kindId": 1,
                "subjectId": 105,
                "name": "Кроссовки",
                "brand": "Reebok",
                "brandId": 777,
                "siteBrandId": 748,
                "sale": 35,
                "priceU": 539900,
                "salePriceU": 350900,
                "pics": 4,
                "rating": 5,
                "feedbacks": 19,
                "colors": [
                    {
                        "name": "белый",
                        "id": 16777215
                    }
                },
                {

                "id": 30304723,
                "root": 22425063,
                "kindId": 1,
                "subjectId": 105,
                "name": "Кроссовки",
                "brand": "adidas",
                "brandId": 21,
                "siteBrandId": 561,
                "sale": 36,
                "priceU": 799900,
                "salePriceU": 511900,
                "pics": 10,
                "rating": 5,
                "feedbacks": 9,
                "colors": [
                    {
                        "name": "серый",
                        "id": 8421504
                    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно распарсить его, то есть преобразовать из строки в объект одного из стандартных типов Python. Для этого Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), а точнее методом [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Данный метод вернёт Вам словарь. Извлекайте из него значения по ключу, пока не доберётесь до нужного.

***Пример:***

```py
import json

s = '{"data":{"products":[{"colors":[{"name":"белый","id":16777215}]}]}}'
d = json.loads(s)

for product in d['data']['products']:
    for color in product['colors']:
        print(color['name'])
        print(color['id'])
```

***stdout:***

```py
белый
16777215
```

Comment: А если, у меня очень много Colors в одном файле, как вывести мне каждый ?

Comment: @Нечеловекинекот С помощью цикла. Добавил его в ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, за еще один глупый вопрос,  но у меня 1700 переменных Colors, то бишь как мне каждую прочитать? Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Нечеловекинекот Вы можете использовать вложенные циклы, чтобы получить все цвета всех продуктов. Обновил ответ